# is it possible that "the first given food determines the behavior of a child/person"?

Tags: behavior, feeding, introversion

In Pakistan, there is a custom that when a child is born we give him a tiny amount of food (something sweet e.g Honey, Dates, Brown Sugar). It is considered that whoever gives the first food to the child, the child will hold his properties or behaviors ( This seems baseless).

But in some cases, the kid actually holds the properties, which is strange. My question is, what is the logical reason to hold such common properites.

**For Example:**

I have two Aunts (Sisters of my mother), and each of the aunt's children (My cousins) are married together (Yeah Cousin marriage is allowed in Muslims). They have a kid, when he was born, I gave him first food (Honey).
Now the kid has some properties like me, e.g he doesn't often play with other kids, he does not talk much, etc... His parents are happy with this as they assume that kid is like me and since I am educated so the kid is going to be educated too.

My concern is, maybe the kid has some problem and we are just trying to justify it in the wrong way.

Is there any possibility that kid got properties from me? As the only common thing between his parents and me is "We have the same maternal grandparents"

Also, I did not spend any time with the kid that we may assume that kid learned that behavior from me. Both of his parents are extroverts than introverts.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any biological or medical sense, but it probably does fit an example of [confirmation bias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). That is, if people believe a certain food conferred personality traits, they will look for those traits in a person. When they find any of them, it will reinforce the first food idea. When some are absent, they will ignore or explain them away rather than reject the first food idea.